# Change Element Type on Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

To start, I'm not even sure if this is possible. I am attempting to change the HTML element type of an element when the viewport is below 500px. The reason for this is because I have a multipage PDF for my element (instead of a spider monkey). The coding in question is as follows:

HTML

```
<title>Agony's Awesome Spot</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/yay.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)" href="small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)" href="medium.css">
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="faqs.js"></script>
<h2>Feats and/or Strengths</h2>
    <div>
        <p>Here is my StackOverflow Profile:<br></br>
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2886993/agony">
            <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2886993.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Agony at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for Agony at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"></a>
        <br></br>Get my resumé here:
        <br></br>
        <embed id="resume" height="900px" width="900px" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/007/cache/spider-monkey_719_600x450.jpg">
        </p>
    </div>
```

I have tried to link to a `<script>` tag based on `media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)"`, but that did not work. Basically what I want to happen is when the user's viewport is under 500px, the `<embed>` becomes a `<a>` tag instead. I can change the CSS accordingly without an issue, but I'm not sure how to change the element tag completely.

I'm unsure how to get a JSFiddle to demonstrate this, so I posted the site [here](http://homepages.uc.edu/~pfeiffbt/test.html).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do it through a media query - have an `embed` and an `a`, and `display: none`/ `display: block` them according to your wishes. The downside of that is that both elements get potentially loaded. To prevent that, you'd have to use JavaScript.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/resize/ is a JavaScript event handler that fires when a window gets resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both tags and manipulate their `display` property

```
<a id="myAnchor" ...>...</a>
<embed id="resume" height="900px" width="900px" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/007/cache/spider-monkey_719_600x450.jpg">
```

and the CSS:

```css
#resume {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and(min-width: 500px) {
    #resume {
        display: block;
    }
    #myAnchor {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but the problem with it is that both elements are likely to get loaded every time, no matter whether they're visible or not. In case of a PDF, that can be costly.

Comment: This was a great approach (seeing as I can be quite the moron and very oblivious sometimes), but it does not work for some reason. When the viewport is resized to under 200, the PDF goes to `display:none`, but the anchor will not show up.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. I love you. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 True, that could be bad. Luckily it's a personal, small website so it's not too big of a deal. Though, I still wonder if there is a way to change an element tag based on viewport. I'll update this question if I ever find a solution.

Comment: @Agony it's possible, but only using JavaScript. Constantly check the current window size - destroy one element and create the other accordingly. If you feel the media query approach works for you, that's fine - but you're taking away the advantage for the mobile user that his device doesn't have to load the PDF?

Comment: @Pekka웃 That would require, as you put, constantly checking. Do you know of a potential solution by using media queries, though? I feel like using a media query to link a `.js` rather than a `.css` would be so much simpler.

Comment: @Agony nope. Media queries can't trigger Javascript. The constant checking isn't a big deal with the `.resize()` handler linked above (if you're willing to use jQuery)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well that's lame! :P Yeah, constant checking isn't that bad, I'm just lazy honestly. And I have yet to learn the syntax for it (still in college), so until then it looks like it is the `display` attributes for me! Thanks for the help, though!